# Why nested list views are not scrolling properly in Android?

Tags: android, xml, listview

[image]I am making a chat application.The problem is my list view is not scrolling.
First, there is a main chat UI containing list view and it is scrolling fine and the main chat UI image is

but there is a view which gets visible on certain event when that event occurs it gets visible and that view is a relative layout containing listview and the image is

[image: This is the image and in this image that invisible is visible]

the more events occur more rows added dynamically in that currently visible view and this list is also scrolling fine but the problem us when one of the rows containing black background is clicked, it expands and it also contains a listview and this list view is not scrolling.I don't know why.Is it happening due to multiple listviews?If not then how can I solve my problem.This is the image after expanding view containing list view that is not scrolling.[image]

Comment: Nested scrollView may cause the problem. To avoid this use dispatch or intercept touch event for `ScrollView` and `ListView`.

Comment: I am not using any scroll view in any of the views

Comment: Why are you using nested listview? I believe you can do the above UI with single ListView.

Comment: 1)firs list view is for main chat
2)second list view is for alert messages and it collects all alerts
3)third is for showing all messages from one of the above alerts

Does nested list view really effects scrolling?